# Character count in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, telemetry

Should I install any plugins or there is build-in way to see the text length? Length in the status line gives me the byte size, not char count.

Comment: The length value in my notepad++ is definitely character count. Typing`1234567890` gives length:10, lines:1. EDIT: Ah, I see it's also counting white space and new lines in that count.

Comment: Yes, spaces is what makes the difference between byte size and char count. It cannot be UTF-8 encoding. Gland to see sombody realizing that whitespace is not a character. Trying the digits proves everything.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

If you double click around 'Length' in status bar, this window will pop up:
[image]

I hope it is what you looking for.

Comment: Also, I was looking for a way to find the length of selected characters. The solution is in the same place. Just make a selection and look at "Sel:" in the summary box or at the bottom of the main window in the status bar

Comment: Thank you for this.  What an atrocious user interface;  there is literally no indication that one can do this.

Comment: View -> Summary...

Comment: Not ideal at all, as it does not include line endings and requires additional action. As a developer, I am fine with bytes. As a writer, I'd like to have characters, because for non-English languages bytes are useless.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the TextFX Characters plugin for Notepad++.

1). Install the plugin.

2). Highlight the text you want to count.

3). From the tool bar "TextFX -> TextFX Tools -> Word Count"

It gives the word count, character count, and other information.

I use Notepad++ v8.1.4 (32-bit)

Comment: I don't know why this got a downvote. Thanks for sharing TextFX!

Answer (score 0):

No plugin is needed.

Just select the text and then look in the status bar below for the letter count.